# Proteger y desproteger una hoja de excel con Python

Tags: python, excel

Hola que tal buenas tardes a todos. Soy bastante nuevo en esto de la programación, recientemente estuve trabajando en un proyecto de "Data enter" en Python para Excel. Es decir, la idea es que mediante un programa creado en Python los usuarios tengan un formulario para ingresar datos y luego insertarlos en Excel. No he tenido demasiados inconvenientes para realizar este trabajo aunque no estoy logrando que una vez realizadas las modificaciones automáticamente se vuelva a proteger el libro para evitar que puedan modificar los datos ingresados.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con la libreria openpyxl la cual me ha resultado muy útil hasta ahora.

un ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando seria:

```
#desproteger la hoja y realizar las modificaciones necesarias mediante el data enter
sheet.unprotect("password") 
#volver a proteger la hoja luego de que el programa haya realizado las modificaciones   
sheet.getProtection().setPassword('password')
```

tambien les dejo parte del codigo que he estado trabajando

```
import os
import openpyxl
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


def enter_data():
    nombre = first_name_entry.get()
    apellido = last_name_entry.get()
 

    print("Nombre: ", nombre, "Apellido: ", apellido)
    filepath= "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Python/Prueba con excel/Viaticos.xlsx" 
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet = workbook.active
    sheet.append([nombre, apellido])

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Viaticos Neutics')
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

user_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Informacion Personal")
user_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    #Name and last name
first_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text="Nombre")
first_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
last_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text = "Apellido")
last_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    #Name and lastname
first_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
first_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
last_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
last_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Insertar", command= enter_data)
button.grid(row=3 , column=0, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=20)

window.mainloop()
```

No dejo el codigo completo ya que es un poco largo. Pero creo que se deja ver el objetivo con esa parte del codigo. Aquel que lo necesite completo puede pedirmelo sin problemas.

Tengan en cuenta que soy bastante nuevo en Python previo a esto solo he desarrollado en Visual Basic y Java. Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado con el documento de ayuda de Openpyxl.
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html
Al principio no lo entendí pero luego comprendí como funciona
Primero se debe importar la configuracion "from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection"
luego crear una contraseña para el archivo

```
ws = workbook.active
ws.protection.password = '123'
```

y ya quedaria listo. El archivo se desprotege solo cuando el dataenter realiza una modificacion